# How to override the message and level with structured logging in Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, logging, stdout

[Doc: Implementing Structured Logging](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#implementing-structured-logging)

```
import json
import logging

class StructuredMessage(object):
    def __init__(self, message, **kwargs):
        self.message = message
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s >>> %s' % (self.message, json.dumps(self.kwargs))

_ = StructuredMessage   # optional, to improve readability

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(message)s')
logging.info(_('message 1', foo='bar', bar='baz', num=123, fnum=123.456))
```

In the Python docs/cookbook, there's an example of how to implement "structured logging", but the example neither shows how to override formatting of the "level" or "message". In most structured logging setups, the "level" and "message" should be properties on the JSON ("level", "msg") log line. Looking through the rest of the doc, it appears that you can add a log formatter in the form of a template string (*ish*), but how would one do so with a function instead? I'd like to apply some transformations like setting the message as a "msg" property on the JSON payload instead of printing it unformatted & doing the same with the "level" but lowercase-ified. I can handle the actual logic for this but am unsure *how* to apply these transformations. Do you have an example for this?

Comment: This was the first hit when i googled 'python json logging' https://github.com/madzak/python-json-logger

Comment: I will try to implement it as such- https://github.com/madzak/python-json-logger/blob/master/src/pythonjsonlogger/jsonlogger.py#L66